# For loop in jinja2 for json file

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am creating an HTML table in Flask by json file.
Here is my json file:

```
{
 "data1": {
  "key1": 49371,
  "key2": 699
 },
 "data2": {
  "key1": 890,
  "key2": 6536
 }
}
```

I have pass json in render_template

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    jsonFile = open("Stats.json", "r")  # Open the JSON file for reading
    data = json.load(jsonFile)  # Read the JSON into the buffer
    jsonFile.close()  # Close the JSON file
    return render_template('index.html', data= data)
```

So how I can create the table row like by jinja2 in flask

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td>
          <td>key1</td>
          <td>key2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data2</td>
          <td>key1</td>
          <td>key2</td>
        </tr>
<tbody>
```

Thanks in advance. This is my first question. sorry, If I did any mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries aren't ordered in the way lists are. If you want rows in order, considering using a format like

```
[
    {
        "key": "data1",
        "field1": 49371,
        "field2": 699
    },
    {
        "key": "data2",
        "field1": 890,
        "field2": 6536
    }
]
```

Then you could use a straightforward template like

```
<table>
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.key }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.field1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.field2 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Key 1</th>
        <th>Key 2</th>
    </tr>
{% for i in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i.key }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.field1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.field2 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```